# Source class "\Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterface" for "Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory" generation does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.1

On my test-server im running magento 2.3.1 after doing composer upgrade the system updated my addons but now when i want to php bin/magento setup:upgrade i recieve the following error:

Source class "\Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterface" for "Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory" generation does not exist.

Now the result is i cant access my server anymore on http but only on ssh.

Anybody have an idea? :)

Comment: Please run the di compile command

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command in your magento root cmd window :-
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Happy to help. pls, accept the answer and upvote so it will help Magento community.

Comment: Already tried to compile, still recieving the same error.  I ran already:
<code>php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile</code>

always recieving the following error:
<code>Source class "\Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterface" for "Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory" generation does not exist.</code>

Comment: i found out that a module was causing the problem, i found out with searching for "emailmessageinterface" and then i saw the module was doing this. i removed and now is this one working perfect.

Comment: That's Great :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it as SteelDragon suggested in his comment:

1. Search for any modules that use:

   ```
   <preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory" [...] />
   ```
2. Disable the found module:

   ```
   bin/magento module:disable [modulename]
   ```
3. Then run:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```